# MDX: Only except in calculated member

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

Is it not possible to just have one except clause in a calculated member? (Without using aggregate)

Like this:

```
MEMBER [Agency].[AgencyName].[Trade] AS (
EXCEPT([Agency].[AgencyName].[All].children, [Agency].[AgencyName].&[Direct Business])
)
```

Comment: What is your goal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of sum aggregation go for:

```
([Agancy].[AgancyName].[All],[Measures].[MyMeasure]) - ([Agancy].[AgancyName].&[Direct Business], [Measures].[MyMeasure])
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with sets? If I want to remove two members

Comment: Why not: All - Member1 - Member2. Do you mean that?

Comment: Yes, I will try it!